# How can I justify plain text in Linux?

Tags: linux, text-editing, alignment, plaintext

I'm composing a plain text (.txt) document that has left-and-right justified paragraphs. I manually add spaces, breaking words with hyphens if necessary, until the lines are uniform length.  To use an example from my document, a paragraph like this:

```
These phantasmic balls have some strange properties, some neat, some
interesting, and others just indicative of lazy design. They're almost all
caused by the same design flaw: The game treats them too much like regular
balls.
```

will end up looking like this:

```
These phantasmic balls have some  strange properties,
some neat,  some interesting, and others just indica-
tive of lazy design. They're almost all caused by the
same design flaw:  The game treats them too much like
regular balls.
```

How can I do this?

It's okay to add spaces (without breaking words over lines), but I need to control the target width of the paragraph (in # characters).  The example above is justified to 53 characters per line, but line width in my actual document varies from 60 to 79.

It'd also be great if there was a text editor with such a feature.

I already tried:

- *OpenOffice* and *TeX*: They just use formatting to change how the text is displayed.
- *nano*'s Justify command doesn't count because it doesn't actually make the lines uniform width.

---

<sub>I accepted the following answer because it was the one that worked best for *me*.  I found the emacs fill commands the easiest to use among the answers, and I appreciate how it recognizes even non-whitespace indentation (for stuff like # and // comments).  However, the other answers all fill their own niches and I recommend others visiting this question to look at them as well.</sub>

Comment: Why? I'm genuinely curious. One of the advantages of plain text it that it's independent of formatting and you can slap it into OpenOffice or TeX and make it look nice. What's your use for this?

Comment: Also, are you looking for this utility to do semi-intelligent hyphenation too?

Comment: The reason is because it's a guide for GameFAQs.  GameFAQs only takes plain text, TXT documents.  As for hyphenation, I'd prefer it, but it isn't an absolute requirement.

Comment: Your AlphaBounce game guide is beautifully formatted. Good job. https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ds/991750-alphabounce/faqs/60669

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in emacs using `fill-paragraph` or `fill-region` ([fill docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fill-Commands.html)).

You need to pass a numeric prefix argument. The default fill column is 70.

Select the text to fill and do `M-3 M-x fill-region`.

I set the fill column to 53 for your sample text and got:

```
These phantasmic balls  have some strange properties,
some   neat,  some   interesting,  and   others  just
indicative of lazy  design. They're almost all caused
by  the same design  flaw: The  game treats  them too
much like regular balls.
```

Comment: That looks good.  I'm installing the package for emacs right now to take a look at this feature.

Comment: Okay, it took quite a bit of tinkering to get used to the unusual interface and terminology (unusual by today's standards, at least), but this is great.  C-x f 53, M-1 M-q.  It's certainly easier than my Plan B (which would've been to write my own Ruby script that justified text), and much to my satisfaction, it even recognizes indentation and takes that into account when justifying. Nice.

Comment: How do I set the fill column to 53 or to any other value I want for that matter? And how can I check what it currently is?

Comment: By the way, the link in your answer is broken.

Comment: I've updated the link

Comment: To check the current value, check the value of the variable `fill-column` (`C-h v` to show variable, then type the name).

To set, hit `C-x f`

Answer (score 23):

you need `par` ([official website](http://www.nicemice.net/par/), [source code](https://bitbucket.org/amc-nicemice/par/), [package status on Repology](https://repology.org/project/par-paragraph-reformatter/versions))

e.g. to get it on ubuntu, do:

```
sudo aptitude install par
```

to justify `text.txt` (at the width of 80 chars), saving in `newtext.txt`:

```
par j1w80 < text.txt > newtext.txt
```

to use par in vim or gvim:

```
:set formatprg=par\ j1w80
```

then highlight the text you want to format and use the `gq` command.

for more information, see `man par`

Comment: I tested this and found it to be quite touchy.  It sometimes results in errors even under what would seem to be the most innocent of circumstances.  In comparison to the emacs command, this is unusable.

Comment: Can you give an example? It seems quite stable to me.

Comment: The command you gave is not correct.  It has to be `par w80 j1`, not `par 80j`. Edit: Or `par jw80`

Comment: Or `par jf` to let `par` determine the best width.

Comment: @sml, I just got one with 1.53 : `par error: Cannot justify.` when attempted to justify a text with a with of 30 characters. Maybe it's a normal behavior though, I don't know. (Upvoted btw, cause I was looking for this command. :-))

Comment: For what it's worth (i.e. for folks seeing this that only want to wrap long lines), vim can do a less-complicated version of this without any external program.  Just set the `textwidth` variable (e.g. `:set textwidth=72` is what I like, so it readily fits within 80 column windows, even with line numbering on), and then use the `gq` command with some movement action... e.g. `gqip` is what I frequently use (see `:help gq` and `:help ip`), though something like `1GgqG` could also be useful, or various other incantations.  See also `:help formatoptions`, `:help wrapmargin`, etc.

Answer (score 7):

`fmt` is the old-school solution

From the man page:

> fmt [-cmnps] [-d chars] [-l num] [-t num]
>            [goal [maximum] | -width | -w width] [file ...]

and

> The goal length
>        defaults to 65 and the maximum to 10 more than the goal length.  Alterna-
>        tively, a single width parameter can be specified either by prepending a
>        hyphen to it or by using -w.  For example, `fmt -w 72'',`fmt -72'',
>        and ``fmt 72 72'' all produce identical output.

Comment: Some versions of `fmt` don't have several of those options and can't do full justification.

Comment: Sorry but you haven't clearly said how exactly to justify text using `fmt`. Also, as Dennis said, on my system the man page doesn't provide any such text as you have mentioned and doesn't say how to justify.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's a Perl script called `paradj`](http://search.cpan.org/~jcduque/paradj/) that can do full justification and hyphenation.

Here's a `diff` showing some changes I made to support adding a left margin:

```
12c12
< my ($indent, $newline);
---
> my ($indent, $margin, $newline);
15a16
>   "margin:i" => \$margin,
21a23
> $margin = 0 if (!$margin);
149a152
>     print " " x $margin;
187a191,193
>   print "--margin=n (or -m=n or -m n)  Add a left margin of n ";
>   print "spaces\n";
>   print "                                (defaults to 0)\n";
```

This command:

```
./paradj.pl -h --width=53 --both --indent=0 inputfile
```

produces output very close to your example (the extra spaces are in different places).

```
These  phantasmic balls have some strange properties,
some  neat, some interesting, and others just indica-
tive of lazy design. They're almost all caused by the
same  design flaw: The game treats them too much like
regular balls.
```

Comment: A great solution that, unfortunately, I cannot use.  About a month ago, I tried to get TeX in Perl because I wanted to use TeX::Hyphen (for a different but related issue to this question).  IIRC, what I discovered was that the Ubuntu repos only have certain parts of the TeX library available, and Hyphen is not among them.  I tried manually installing the Perl TeX library, but that did not work out well.  I ended up breaking Perl and spent the next few hours undoing the damage.  I'm reluctant to give it another go.  I wish I had enough rep to at least give you a +1 for this answer, though.

Comment: @Exp HP: I'm sorry you had so much trouble. I've got this on a Ubuntu 9.10 system and I've no problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Perl script `reformat`. It does not justify text with multi-byte characters correctly and does not use hyphenation, though.

You can install it on Debian/Ubuntu, by running `sudo apt-get install reformat`.

Use it like this:

```
reformat -w 53 -j < mytext.txt
```

The justified text will be written to standard output:

```
These phantasmic balls have  some strange properties,
some  neat,  some   interesting,  and  others    just
indicative of lazy design.  They're almost all caused
by the same  design  flaw: The game  treats  them too
much like regular balls.
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Nano.

Rename the file to a shorter name (8.3). Open in Nano, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> to justify the whole document. <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> to save. Then <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> to exit. Then rename the file back to the original name.

Might sound cumbersome but it saved me a lot of time over doing the manual <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd> to limit the columns to 90. Nano defaults to 72. I can live with that.

Comment: What is the magic behind the short file name?

Answer (score 0):

To add some info about the paradj programme from Julius C. Duque mentionned above by Dennis Williamson, I have slightly modified this tool to suit need for bulleted / numbered paragraphs. I enclose the code below.

I tried to contact the original author (J.C. Duque) on CPAN to let him keep trace of those changes but to no avail, his email address is no longer valid.

NB: tested on perl 5.032/64b on Win 10.

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

# *******************
# * Julius C. Duque *
# *******************

=for comment

  This version of this tool is dated 2023-04-26 10:07:51.
  
  It is the modified version of the original Julius-C.-Duque's paradj.pl tool I
  found on internet with the modification code by Denis Williamson, from
  superuser.com site.

  See https://www.cpan.org/authors/id/J/JC/JCDUQUE/paradj-1.3.0.pl for the
  original 1.30 (2003 November 16) version of this file.
  MANY MANY thanks to him for this tool.

  I added myself some changes I was in need to handle paragraphs with numbered
  or bulleted first lines such as:
    1. Title: bla bla ...
    bal bla bla...

    2. Title: fuh fuh ...
    fuh fuh fuh...
  to produce:
    1. title: bla ... blah  blah
       bla bla ... ... ...  blah

  Some lines added to implement left margin option according to indications
  provided by Denis Williamson at:
  https://superuser.com/questions/171616/how-can-i-justify-plain-text-in-linux

  Each such line is flaged w/ comment "# Denis Williamson". Many thanks to him.
  Gilles Maisonneuve. 2023-04-25 11:59:11.

  Added option '--firstlineMargin' to allow any paragraph first lines that
  starts with a bullet / a paragraph number... to have a reduced margin
  compared to the margin of the remaining part of the subsquent paragraph.
  If not set, takes the same value as the $margin. See the POD "for comment"
  block at end of file to read an example of '--firstlineMargin' usage.

  Also added some option-handling "enhancement" such as --help and exit on
  invalid option. Side effect: '--hyphenate' can no longer be abbreviated into
  '-h' but must be typed in at least as '-hy'.

  Gilles Maisonneuve, 2023-04-25 13:38:31

=cut

use diagnostics;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use TeX::Hyphen;

my ($width, $hyphenate, $left, $centered, $right, $both);
my ($indent, $margin, $newline);  # Denis Williamson
my $firstlineMargin;              # Gilles Maisonneuve
my $help;                         # Gilles Maisonneuve

# Corrected '"help" => \$hyphenate' into '"hyphenate" => \$hyphenate', from
# original code.
# Gilles Maisonneuve, 2023-04-25 13:27:13

GetOptions("width=i" => \$width, "hyphenate" => \$hyphenate,
  "left" => \$left, "centered" => \$centered,
  "margin:i" => \$margin,         # Denis Williamson
  "first-line-margin=i" => \$firstlineMargin,
  "right" => \$right, "both" => \$both,
  "indent:i" => \$indent, "newline" => \$newline, "help"=>\$help)
  # Can't use die() due to 'use diagnostics' set by Julius Duque; GM, 23-04-25
  or exit( print(STDERR "See '--help' to get help\n") && 9 );

my $hyp = new TeX::Hyphen;

# Modified to handle 'help' option, GM:
syntax() if !$width or defined $help;
$indent = 0 if (!$indent);
$margin = 0 if !$margin;          # Denis Williamson

# Gilles Maisonneuve
$firstlineMargin = $margin if not defined $firstlineMargin;

local $/ = "";

while (<>) {
  my @linein = split;
  printpar(@linein);
  print "\n" if ($newline);
}

sub printpar
{
  my (@par) = @_;
  my $firstline = 0;

  while (@par) {
    $firstline++;
    my ($buffer, $word);
    my ($charcount, $wordlen) = (0, 0);
    # my $linewidth = $width;
    # Seems to have be a little oversight in Denis Williamson algorithm: margin
    # is not counted in line size when folding. Trying to correct it.
    # Gilles Maisonneuve. 2023-04-26 08:39:58
    my $linewidth = $width - $margin;

    if ($firstline == 1) {
      $linewidth -= $indent;
      # For 1st lines of each paragraph let's try to handle specific line
      # margin, thus do not handle its margin with the global margin it it has
      # its own value.
      # Gilles Maisonneuve, 2023-04-26 08:42:39
      if ($firstlineMargin != $margin) {  # restore original paragraph width
        $linewidth += $margin;            # for 1st line, if not same margins,
        $linewidth -= $firstlineMargin;   # but remove specific 1st line margin.
      };                                  # GM.
      print " " x $indent;
    }

    while (($charcount < $linewidth) and (@par)) {
      $word = shift @par;
      $buffer .= $word;
      $wordlen = length($word);
      $charcount += $wordlen;
      $buffer .= " ";
      $charcount++;
    }

    chop $buffer;
    $charcount--;

    if ($charcount == $wordlen) {
      $linewidth = $wordlen;
      my ($pos, $pre_word_len) = (0, 0);
      if ($hyphenate) {
        if ($word =~ /^([^a-zA-Z]*)([a-zA-Z-']+)([^a-zA-Z]*)$/) {
          my $pre_word = $1;
          $pre_word_len = length($pre_word);
          my $stripped_word = $2;
          $pos = hyphenate_word($stripped_word, $width);
          $pos = 0 if ($wordlen <= $width);
        }

        if ($pos) {
          $charcount = $pre_word_len + $pos;
          my $post_word = substr $word, $charcount;
          unshift(@par, $post_word);
          $buffer = substr $word, 0, $charcount;
          $buffer .= "-";
          $charcount++;
        }
      }
    }

    my $lineout = $buffer;

    if ($charcount > $linewidth) {
      my ($pos, $pre_word_len) = (0, 0);
      if ($hyphenate) {
        if ($word =~ /^([^a-zA-Z]*)([a-zA-Z-']+)([^a-zA-Z]*)$/) {
          my $pre_word = $1;
          $pre_word_len = length($pre_word);
          my $stripped_word = $2;
          my $unfilled = $linewidth - $charcount + $wordlen
            - $pre_word_len + 1;

          $pos = hyphenate_word($stripped_word, $unfilled);
        }
      }

      $charcount -= $wordlen;

      if ($pos == 0) {
        $charcount--;
        unshift(@par, $word);
      } else {
        my $post_word = substr $word, ($pre_word_len + $pos);
        unshift(@par, $post_word);
        $charcount = $charcount + $pre_word_len + $pos;
      }

      $lineout = substr $buffer, 0, $charcount;

      if ($pos) {
        $lineout .= "-";
        $charcount++;
      }
    }

    my $spaces_to_fill = $linewidth - $charcount;

    if ($centered) {
      my $leftfill = int($spaces_to_fill/2);
      print " " x $leftfill;
    } elsif ($right) {
      print " " x $spaces_to_fill;
    } elsif ($both) {                   # justified left and right column
      my $tempbuf = $lineout;
      my $replacements_made = 0;

      if (@par) {
        my $reps = 1;

        while (length($tempbuf) < $linewidth) {
          last if ($tempbuf !~ /\s/);
          if ($tempbuf =~ /(\S+ {$reps})(\S+)/) {
            $tempbuf =~ s/(\S+ {$reps})(\S+)/$1 $2/;
            $replacements_made++;
            $tempbuf = reverse $tempbuf;
          } else {
            $reps++;
          }
        }
      }; # if (@par)

      if ($replacements_made % 2 == 0) {
        $lineout = $tempbuf;
      } else {
        $lineout = reverse $tempbuf;
      }
    }; # } elsif ($both) # justified left and right column
    # print " " x $margin;          # Denis Williamson
    print " " x $margin if $firstline != 1;   # Gilles Maisonneuve
    print " " x $firstlineMargin if $firstline == 1;
    if ($firstline == 1) {
      $lineout =~ s/^([^ \t]*)([ \t]*)(.*)/$1 $3/;
      my $firstblanksCount = length($2)-1;
      while ($firstblanksCount) {
        $lineout =~ m{^([^ \t]*)(.*)};
        my $head = $1; my $tail = $2;
        # Add ONE space after (in sequence) each one of 'full stop', 'comma',
        # 'semicolon', and 'colon'.
        $tail =~ s/(.*?[\.\,\;\:] )([^ \t]+.*)/$1 $2/
          # or, after all the above punctuation signs have been "exhausted",
          # start add space for each single space in the line.
          or $tail =~ s/^([^ ]+ .*?)( )([^ ]*.*)/$1$2 $3/
          or $tail =~ s/([^ ] )([^ ])/$1 $2/
          # or, if everything exhausted or failed, just give up and leave the
          # line with poor formatting... (I'm not good enough in algorithm to
          # know how to solve this kind of cases).
          # Gilles Maisonneuve, 2023-04-26 09:45:34
          or last;
        $lineout = $head . $tail;
        $firstblanksCount--;
      }; # while ($firstblanksCount)
    }; # if ($firstline == 1)
    print "$lineout\n";
  }; # while (@par)
}; # sub printpar

sub hyphenate_word
{
  my ($tword, $unfilled) = @_;
  my @hyphen_places = $hyp->hyphenate($tword);

  if (@hyphen_places) {
    @hyphen_places = reverse @hyphen_places;

    foreach my $places (@hyphen_places) {
      return $places if ($places < $unfilled - 1);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

sub syntax
{
  # Gilles Maisonneuve, 2023-04-25 12:12:03.
  my $pgmname=$0;
  # remove Windows file path to display short name in the help synopsis.
  # Win file paths are either DISK-LETTER:\...\ (computer local) or \\... (UNC)
  # for remote (network disk) files.
  $pgmname =~ s/^[A-Z]:\\.*\\|^\\\\.*\\//i if $^O eq 'MSWin32';
  # I assume all other OSes are Unix compliant ! (GM)
  $pgmname =~ s{/.*/}{} if $^O ne 'MSWin32';

  print "Usage:\n";
  print "  $pgmname --width=n [options] file1 [file2 file3 ...]\n";
  print "  cat file1 [file2 file3 ...] | $pgmname --width=n [options]\n\n";
  print "Credits:\n";
  print "   Original author: Julius C. Duque.\n";
  print "   Margin option: Denis Williamson.\n";
  print "   First line margin option: Gilles Maisonneuve.\n";
  print "\n";
  print "Options:\n";
  print "--width=n (or -w=n or -w n)     Line width is n chars long.\n";
  print "--left (or -l)                  Left-justified (default).\n";
  print "--right (or -r)                 Right-justified.\n";
  print "--centered (or -c)              Centered.\n";
  print "--both (or -b)                  Both left- and right-justified.\n";
  print "--indent=n (or -i=n or -i n)    Leave n spaces for initial indention",
        "\n", ' ' x 32, "(defaults to 0).\n";
  # Denis Williamson:
  print "--margin=n (or -m=n or -m n)    Add a left margin of n spaces.\n";
  print "--first-line-margin n (-f n)    Set each paragraph first line margin.",
        " Allows\n", ' ' x 32, "to set a smaller margin for bulleted lines.\n";
  print "--newline (or -n)               Output an empty line between ",
        "paragraphs.\n";
  print "--hyphenate (or -hy)            Hyphenate word that doesn't fit on a",
        "line.\n";
  print "--help (or -he)                 This help text.\n";
  exit 0;
}


=head1 NAME

paradj - a small Perl script that reformats lines of ASCII text so that
the resulting lines are  justified in any of the following formats:
left-justified  (default), right-justified, centered, or both left- and
right-justified.

=head1 README

Paragraph Adjuster with Hyphenation (PAwH) is a small Perl script that
reformats lines of ASCII text so that the resulting lines are justified
in  any  of  the following  formats:  left-justified  (default),
right-justified, centered, or both left- and right-justified. PAwH has
various  switches, most are optional, to control its output. The  only
mandatory switch is the line width (--width). For PAwH to work properly,
input paragraphs must be separated by blank lines.

PAwH is also capable of hyphenating a word that cannot be accommodated
on a line.

=head1 DESCRIPTION

Paragraph Adjuster with Hyphenation (PAwH) is a small Perl script that
reformats lines of ASCII text so that the resulting lines are justified
in  any  of  the following  formats:  left-justified  (default),
right-justified, centered, or both left- and right-justified. PAwH has
various  switches, most are optional, to control its output. The  only
mandatory switch is the line width (--width). For PAwH to work properly,
input paragraphs must be separated by blank lines.

PAwH is also capable of hyphenating a word that cannot be accommodated
on a line.

=head1 USAGE

You can use PAwH in any of two ways:

./paradj.pl.pl --width=n [options] file1 [file2 file3 ...]

or

cat file1 [file2 file3 ...] | ./paradj.pl --width=n [options]

where file1, file2, file3, and so on, are the files to be reformatted.
There's only one output, though.

=head1 SWITCHES

The available switches are:

--width=n (or -w=n or -w n)
    Line width is n chars long

--left (or -l)
    Output is left-justified (default)

--right (or -r)
    Output is right-justified

--centered (or -c)
    Output is centered

--both (or -b)
    Output is both left- and right-justified

--indent=n (or -i=n or -i n)
    Leave n spaces for initial indention (defaults to 0)

--newline (or -n)
    Insert blank lines between paragraphs

--hyphenate (or -h)
    Hyphenate word that doesn't fit on a line

=head1 EXAMPLES

The  following command reformats the file, LICENSE,  so that the line
width is at most 70 characters,  both left-  and right-justified, with
blank lines inserted between consecutive  paragraphs,  and words that
can't fit at the end of lines are hyphenated.

paradj.pl --width=70 --both --newline --hyphenate LICENSE

You can also use the shortened version:

paradj.pl -w=70 -b -n -h LICENSE

If  you  want to indent each paragraph, just use the --indent  switch.
Say, you want to indent the LICENSE file with 4 leading spaces, type:

paradj.pl --width=70 --both --newline --hyphenate --indent=4 LICENSE

or

paradj.pl -w=70 -b -n -h -i=4 LICENSE


=head1 GUI VERSION

There is also a Perl/Tk version of paradj.pl, called paradj-tk.pl.

=head1 PREREQUISITE

You  need Jan Pazdziora's Perl module, TeX::Hyphen, available from the
Comprehensive Perl Archive Network (CPAN), to use the hyphenation
feature. The latest is version 0.140.

For  Windows  users,  you can install TeX::Hyphen by  following  these
steps:

1. Uncompress the TeX::Hyphen module, TeX-Hyphen-0.140.tar.gz.

2.  Descend (cd) into the TeX-Hyphen-0.140/lib and copy the TeX directory
into <Perl directory>\lib. For example, if your Perl binaries are
installed on E:\Perl, copy the TeX directory into E:\Perl\lib.

=head1 COPYRIGHT AND LICENSE

Copyright (C) 2003 Julius C. Duque <{jcduque}{at}{lycos}{dot}{com}>

This  library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or  modify
it under the same terms as the GNU General Public License.

=pod SCRIPT CATEGORIES

CPAN/Administrative
Fun/Educational

=cut



=for comment

An example of usage with a simple text file: lets assume that file.txt contains
the following text (here placed between >>> and <<< markers):
>>>
This paragraph has no bullet nor indexed paragraph title at its left margin, therefore
it should remain unchanged beside its regular reformat fill process. The First Line
margin should be the same as the regular paragraph margin and no "first blank" counts
should interfere.

1. no expand,  "flat" but separate,  numbered pages, unique  and incrementally
numbered chapters + paragraphs.

2. Split documentation in multiple pages: when  reading a subject, a page that
extend on more than 2 / 3 screen height tends to be difficult to read.

3. Insert a Table of Contents at top of page.

4. When using sub-pages (large doc): use a multi-page "table of contents"
which is the Confluence macro named: "Children Display".
<<<

the following commands will produce the ensuing results:

$ paradj --width=78 --both --margin=3 --first=0 --newline file.txt
>>>
This paragraph  has no bullet nor indexed paragraph title at its left  margin,
   therefore  it  should  remain unchanged beside its  regular  reformat  fill
   process.  The First Line margin should be the same as the regular paragraph
   margin and no "first blank" counts should interfere.

1. no  expand,  "flat" but separate, numbered pages, unique and  incrementally
   numbered chapters + paragraphs.

2. Split documentation in multiple pages:  when reading a subject, a page that
   extend on more than 2 / 3 screen height tends to be difficult to read.

3. Insert a Table of Contents at top of page.

4. When  using  sub-pages (large doc):  use a multi-page "table  of  contents"
   which is the Confluence macro named: "Children Display".
<<<

$ paradj --width=78 --both --margin=3 --newline file.txt
>>>
   This paragraph  has  no  bullet  nor indexed paragraph title  at  its  left
   margin,  therefore  it should remain unchanged beside its regular  reformat
   fill  process.  The  First Line margin should be the same  as  the  regular
   paragraph margin and no "first blank" counts should interfere.

   1. no expand, "flat" but separate, numbered pages, unique and incrementally
   numbered chapters + paragraphs.

   2. Split  documentation in multiple pages:  when reading a subject, a  page
   that extend on more than 2 / 3 screen height tends to be difficult to read.

   3. Insert a Table of Contents at top of page.

   4. When using sub-pages (large doc):  use a multi-page "table of  contents"
   which is the Confluence macro named: "Children Display".
<<<

=cut
```

Answer (score 0):

Vim has a bundled plugin called `justify`. Check `:h usr_25` / `:h 25.2`.

Basically:

- `:packadd justify` (or add in `.vimrc` as described to load by default.)
- Select text and  etc.

  - press `_j`
  - `:'<,'>Justify`
  - `:Justify` for whole file
  - etc.

It also adds a mapping to `,gq` which can be OK to run before justifying.

If one want to run it as a silent process on a file one can add a simple process script, for example something like:

```sh
#! /bin/bash -

for opt in "$@"; do
    case $opt in
    -h|--help)
        printf 'Usage: %s FILE [width [write]]\n' \
            "$(basename $0)" >&2
        exit
    esac
done

file=$1
write=
# Change to desired default width
declare -i textwidth=78
[ $# -gt 1 ] && textwidth=$2
[ $# -gt 2 ] && write=$3

end='q!'

case $write in
w|write|-w|--write) end='wq' ;;
esac

if ! [ -t 0 ] || [ "$file" = '-' ]; then
    file=/dev/stdin
fi
# Enforce q! on stdin data
[ "$file" = '/dev/stdin' ] && end='q!'

vim --clean -Nnu NONE -T dumb -es \
    -c"set et tw=$textwidth cpo=Be ft=text|pa justify|norm,gq|,gq|gggqG|_j" \
    -c"%print|$end" \
    -- "$file"
```

*(I have added some extra `,gq` and `gggqG` as there has been some issues with text containing multiple consecutive spaces and end of paragraphs ending in one word.)*

---

It does however not break words. One can do that manually and reformat, so it's a middle ground.

```
These phantasmic balls have some strange  properties,
some neat, some interesting, and others just  indica-
tive of lazy design. They're almost all caused by the
same design flaw: The game treats them too much  like
regular balls.
```